# 404 error with Webpack extract text plugin for styles.css file

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // the main entry of our app
    entry: ['./src/index.js', './src/services/auth/index.js','./src/dist/js/drop-down.js'],
    // output configuration
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build/',
        publicPath: 'build/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // process *.vue files using vue-loader
            {test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue'},
            // process *.js files using babel-loader
            // the exclude pattern is important so that we don't
            // apply babel transform to all the dependencies!
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/},

            {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ],
    babel: {
        presets: ['es2015'],
        plugins: ['transform-runtime']
    }
};
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "somename",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "somelicense",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.0.14",
    "css-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.2.1",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "vue": "^1.0.7",
    "vue-resource": "^0.1.17",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.5"
  }
}
```

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

When I run the webpack server using 
`webpack-dev-server --inline --hot`

I get 404 error for `http://localhost:8080/build/styles.css`

Is there a way to check that styles.css is getting generated or not?(Maybe somewhere other than the `/build`)

And how do I fix this 404 error?

Comment: When you use webpack dev server your styles.css will be served from memory. So if you hadn't built your styles.css file to your build folder I would assume that when using the dev server your styles will still show up, but you will still get the 404 because you are requesting the asset that doesn't exist yet. One solution could be building with webpack then starting the dev server after your styles.css was built to `/build`. But I think importing your styles in the root of your app would also solve the problem. You wouldn't need to request the styles from the html file.

Comment: I think build folder is already there in memory because build/build.js file does exist and does not give 404.